# WordPress doing ajax returns always 0 but should return 1 in some cases

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've created an AJAX function in WordPress for my plugin. In the plugin construct I'm defining the AJAX callback:

```
public function __construct() {
    return $this->register();
}

/**
 * Register all new files in WooCommerce hooks
 */
public function register() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );
    } else {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );
    }
}
```

---

This is the jQuery function which triggers the AJAX call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.filter-menu li', function () {
        var filter_value = jQuery(this).find('.menu-data-inner');

            var data = {
                'action': 'filter',
                'filter': filter_value.attr('data-value'),
                'filter_status': 1
            };      

            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
                jQuery('#content-area').load(location.href + ' #content-area>*', '');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

At the end of my request I refresh the WordPress main content via AJAX and expect here that my function in the `functions.php` get's skipped because of `DOING_AJAX`.

---

This is function which get's called by the AJAX request:

```
/**
 * Filter
 */
public function filter() {
    require 'functions/filter.php';
    wp_die();
}
```

---

This is the content of the require:

```
<?php error_log( $_POST['filter'] ); ?>
```

---

So my problem is now that I've added this function to my `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'do_something' );
function do_something() {
    error_log('INIT');
}
```

---

But I saw very fast that this causes a problem because the init get's called on AJAX request too but I don't want that. It should just print `INIT` when the page loaded via pressing `F5` or entering the site URL and press enter. So I've added a check:

```
add_action( 'init', 'do_something' );
function do_something() {
    if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        error_log('INIT')
    }
}
```

---

But after calling the AJAX again, the debug log print's INIT too but it shouldn't. So I've tried to modify my function called during the AJAX this way:

```
<?php 
    error_log( $_POST['filter'] ); 

    define( 'DOING_AJAX', true ); ?>
```

### But this didn't made it too. The `error_log` is still there.

So what is the problem? What I'm doing wrong here? I mean I've did it like in the DOCS but it seems that DOING_AJAX don't works for me.

Comment: Instead of using the function wp_doing_ajax() try using the expression "defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX".

Answer (score 1):

you need

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );`

for every time you send ajax request
but this

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );`

when you need this that user not logged in
so this gonna change to :

```
public function register() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );
    } else {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', array( $this, 'filter' ) );
    }
}
```

this is why you get 0 for any request i guess